# When connecting LED tape lights to a transformer, should I daisy chain the strips or install home runs for each strip?

Tags: wiring, led

I'm in the planning stage for adding under cabinet LED tape lighting. I have four seperate cabinet areas to reach.

Before I drywall I'm planning to install a standard wall switch that goes to an outlet that will be in the upper part of the cabinet.

Later I can then add a low voltage transformer and a remote dimmer in that cabinet. My question is how to get power to four different cabinet areas. I have attic access.

Is it possible to attach homeruns to the transformer, or do I need to daisy chain down and have a wire go down each cabinet and back up to get to the next one.

Comment: For the sake of simplicity, I'd pre-wire 4 complete runs through the attic of suitable low voltage wire directly from the transformer location to the eventual termination points. Connect them in parallel and you should be good to go. Side note, led strip lights seem to vary widely from their published specs, so it might be good to err on the side of caution when sizing the transformer. PS, appreciate the rewrite... your question is much more clear than it was.

Answer (score 1):

LED lights can typically be chained several times. Read the package. It's almost always stated quite clearly. To be safe with in-wall wiring, you could halve the recommendation and have confidence that it'll work fine.